# Is there a good way to zip/merge together an unknown X-number of lists?

Tags: python

If you know the number of lists, I can merge/zip them together via:

```
x1 = [1,2,3,4]
x2 = [2,3,4,5]
newx = zip(x1,x2)
>>> [(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5)]
```

However, my situation is that I have a list of lists, with unknown dimensions, i.e. `list = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],... [4,5,6,7]]`

I want to zip them up together so that it ultimately looks like:

```
zippedlist = [(1,2,... 4), (2,3,...,5) ... (4,5,...7)]
```

As you can see, it is way easy if I know how many elements ahead of time, and can manually code in `zippedlist = [list[0], list[1], list[2] ... ].`

However, because I am performing a feature selection method, I have no idea how many dimensions my final list will be, and zipping them together is bit tricky. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938786/how-would-you-zip-an-unknown-number-of-lists-in-python?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Argument unpacking.

```
zip(*lists)
```

Comment: Such short answers without any explanation unnecesarilly fill up the Low Quality review queue.  It is really long now.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
zip(*lists)
```

Hope it helps.