# zip unknown number of lists with Python for more than one list

Tags: python, list, zip

I need to do something very similar to what was asked here [How would you zip an unknown number of lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938786/how-would-you-zip-an-unknown-number-of-lists-in-python), but in a more general case.

I have the following set up:

```
a = [['a', '0', 'b', 'f', '78']]
b = [['3', 'w', 'hh', '12', '8']]
c = [['g', '7', '1', 'a0', '9'], ['45', '4', 'fe', 'h', 'k']]
```

I need to zip these lists together to obtain:

```
abc =  [['a', '3', 'g', '45'], ['0', 'w', '7', '4'], ['b', 'hh', '1', 'fe'], ['f', '12', 'a0', 'h'], ['78', '8', '9', 'k']]
```

which I can generate with:

```
zip(a[0], b[0], c[0], c[1])
```

But the lists `a,b,c` contain a number of sublists that will vary for successive runs, so this "manual" way of expanding them won't work.

The closest I can get is:

```
zip(a[0], b[0], *c)
```

Since unpacking a list with `*` in any other position than the last is not allowed, the "ideal" expression:

```
zip(*a, *b, *c)
```

does not work.

How could I zip together a number of lists with an unknown number of sublists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`itertools.chain` to the rescue:

```
import itertools

z = list(zip(*itertools.chain(a, b, c)))
```

Comment: Thank you Israel! I need to start using `itertools` more often.

Comment: You're welcome. Indeed, itertools contains some useful functions, like `groupby`, `product`, `permutations`, `combinations` and more. Great module, based on generators.